# Re-Invoke jQuery Tablesorter after destroy

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

On page load I initialize the tablesorter like so:

```
$('#tableId').tablesorter({ 
    // sort on the first column, order asc 
    sortList: [[5,1]],
    cssDesc: "headerSortDownFan",
    cssAsc: "headerSortUpFan",
    cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort",
    headers: {
        ".sortingDisabled": {
            sorter: false
                }
    },
    // apply custom widget
    widgets: ['numbering']
});
```

Then on a click event I destroy it with:

```
$('#tableId').trigger("destroy");
```

When I go to re-intialize by invoking the following again:

```
$('#tableId').tablesorter({ 
    // sort on the first column, order asc 
    sortList: [[5,1]],
    cssDesc: "headerSortDownFan",
    cssAsc: "headerSortUpFan",
    cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort",
    headers: {
        ".sortingDisabled": {
            sorter: false
                }
    },
    // apply custom widget
    widgets: ['numbering']
});
```

The tablesorter no longer works.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of tablesorter are you using? The original version doesn't have a destroy method. After that, please set up a demo showing the problem.